# CRM 2011 List component for SharePoint - customise column widths

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

### Environment

I am using the native document management integration between Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft SharePoint 2010, via the CRM 2011 List component for SharePoint. There is nothing unusual about this deployment - it is configured to work with contacts and accounts and it all works as documented.

### Requirements

I originally had several requirements (though in the course of writing this question, I have <strike>solved two of them</strike>)

1. <strike>Customise the columns shown to include custom columns (as already
   defined in the List via SP)</strike>
2. <strike>Customise the default sort order</strike>
3. Customise the default column width for some columns

### What I know so far

What I have learned is that the default view for the SharePoint Library seems to drive much of the behaviour of the component. Adding my custom columns to the Library's default view, causes them to appear in the List component output (I don't believe that this is documented anyway - please shout up if you think it is). The column ordering and the view sort order from the default view drive the List component too. Happy days - two requirements met.

SharePoint, via the web UI, doesn't allow column widths to be set (as they are rendered with dynamic widths) so Library Settings is no help here. Using SharePoint Designer to manually set the width on the columns also fails to get inherited by the List component.

The underlying pages that are installed to SharePoint and during installation of the List component sit in a ".../crmgrid/" sub directory. Of the available pages, `crmgridpage.aspx` seems to do all the rendering. SharePoint Designer is keen to tell me that "This page does not contain any regions that you have permissions to edit".

### The Question

Is there any (innovative?) way for me to customise the default column width for some of the columns I am displaying via the List component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have limited options here.  Because you're dealing with multiple domains, you run into cross domain scripting issues ruling out any javascript on the crm form.

The only way that comes to mind is to modify the crmgridpage.aspx page on your sharepoint server to set the width of the columns via javascript.  It's totally unsupported though.

Comment: Appreciate your effort to reply Paul. While I'm not expecting someone to do all the work for me, this isn't really a solution - more a hunch that it might be possible. I will of course give it a go though. Your point on the cross-domain issue is well received.

Comment: Which I'd appreciated that I would lose my bounty points if I didn't award them... (RTFM!!) Paul - had I realised this, I would have awarded your response. Hope it didn't appear petty to have withheld them, knowing now that I thought I'd get them back!

Comment: Hi guys, I know it's been a long time ago, but maybe some of you remembers, where `crmgridpage.aspx` is located on `SP` machine? I'm struggling to find it. And would appreciate your help a lot!